# Normalizing a Data Dictionary

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, normalization

I'm creating a data dictionary for an organization which pulls together fields found in many different sources and defines them.  I have all the data in another Access database, but it is a relational mess.  I'm quite new to Access, and I'm currently trying to normalize the database and migrate the data over.

The sources are currently Extracts and Reports.  More sources will be coming soon.  There are 2 subdivisions of Extracts (Old and New), each with multiple sub-subdivisions.  There are 6 subdivisions of Reports with no further sub-subdivisions.  Fields appear in anywhere between 1 and all reports and extracts.  Data definitions are mostly the same no matter where the field appears, but are sometimes different.  Data definitions are consistent within the Extract subdivision, but can differ between Extracts and Reports, as well as within Reports.  Data types are often different for the same field name in different reports.

My tables in the normalized database (so far) are: Field Info, Sources, and Definition.  The structure of each is as follows,

```
Tbl_[Field Info]    
Field Name (PK)         Full Name
---------------         ---------------------------
TSN                     Transaction Sequence Number
```

I think this is right becase Full Name does not vary by Field Name.

```
Tbl_[Sources]
Sources (PK)
-------------
New Extracts
Old Extracts
```

This is where I start thinking things are wrong.  Surely Sources should have something else in the table other than the sources themselves?

```
Tbl_[Definitions]
ID (PK)             Field Name (FK)             Source              Definition
-------             ----------------            -----------         ---------------
1                   TSN                         Old Extracts        blahblah
2                   TSN                         New Extracts        blahblah
3                   ABC                         New Extracts        asdfghjkl
```

This is where I feel I must be going wrong.  I repeat the same definitions quite frequently inside the Definitions table.

Does my system of organization so far make sense?  I hope to add more fields detailing the data type and whether the field is numeric or not at a later date.

Comment: *"Surely Sources should have something else in the table other than the sources themselves?"* Possibly, but not necessarily. Do people need to know anything about "New Extracts" besides its name?

Comment: Is the Source column in the Definitions table an FK, validated by the PK in the Sources table?

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you identified all the functional dependencies in the data you have so far.

Comment: "functional dependencies" could you clarify what that means?  Sorry, quite new to this normalization business.  You are correct, the source column in the definitions table is an FK validated by the PK in the sources table.

Comment: If a determines b, then b is functionally dependent on a.  The article in wikipedia is not good for a newbie.  If I find a better one, I'll let you know.  In the meantime, you can't learn normalization without learning functional dependency.  Sorry, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic expecation that 'TSN' in both the old and the new extract would have then same definition, and all other attributes.

When creating data maps, with your criteria I try and join the old and the new in single line with new to the left which would give you this

```
Tbl_[Definitions]
ID (PK)             Field Name (FK)             Source              Definition          Field Name (Old)             Source (old)             Definition (old)

-------             ----------------            -----------         ---------------      -------             ----------------            -----------         ---------------

1                   TSN                         Old Extracts        blahblah                   TSN                         New Extracts        blahblah

2                   ABC                         New Extracts        asdfghjkl
```

Comment: Sometimes that does not hold though.  I might have a field Field1 which means one thing in Old Extracts and half of the Reports, another thing in New Extracts, a third in another report, and not appear at all in the remaining 2 reports.  End users will be accessing the database through a form, and will expect to see all possible definitions for one field name, which is why I'm trying to structure the database properly

Answer (score 0):

The construction of a decent relational model for a data dictionary is a problem that has been kicking around for over thirty years.  It is not a simple problem.  There is a considerable body of literature on this subject, and some of it is useful.  There are also a lot of products that address the issue of managing a data dictionary, but learning the data model from those products can be very difficult.

You say you are new to Access, but you don't say whether you have extensive experience with some other relational database system, like SQLServer or Oracle among others.  If you are a beginner at relational modeling, I suggest you have a long learning curve ahead of you before you can come up with a decent model for a Data Dictionary.

Comment: I am new to relational databases both as a concept and as an application. Do you have any suggestions of things to start reading?

Comment: I did a google search on "how to build a data dictionary" and got several hits. One of them, from Ehow, says how to build one in Access. I can't vouch for that answer, but I've had good luck with Ehow in other matters. You might want to read the Wikipedia Article on Data Dictionary. I'm sorry, but I stopped reading about data dictionaries sometime in the 1980s. Maybe some other participant can refer you to current literature.